# python read specific lines from file and continue

Tags: python, loops, readlines

I am trying to read specific lines from file and continue reading after ending the process of each chunk. 
Let's say, I have 19000 lines in a file. Each time, I will extract first 19 lines,make some calculation with those lines and write the output in another file. Then I will extract again the next 19 lines and do the same processing. So, I tried to extract lines in the following way:

```
n=19
x = defaultdict(list)

i=0

fp = open("file")
for next_n_lines in izip_longest(*[fp] *n):
    lines = next_n_lines

    for i, line in enumerate(lines): 
        do calculation
    write results
```

Here the code works for first chunk. Could any of you please help me, how can I continue for next n number of chunk ? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Your code already iterates lines in groups of 19 lines. What is the problem?

Comment: @Francis Avila : The problem I face here is to go for next chunk. It works only for first chunk.

Comment: No, it will iterate all chunks. Are you sure there isn't another problem with code you are not showing? Maybe a `break` somewhere?

Comment: @Francis Avila: Actually, in the 2nd for loop I am having trouble. I want to work with first chunk in 2nd for loop, after writing the results of first chunk then I want to move again for next chunk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code already extracts lines in groups of 19 lines so I'm not sure what your issue is.

I can clean up your solution slightly, but it does the same thing as your code:

```
from itertools import izip_longest

# grouping recipe from itertools documentation
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "Collect data into fixed-length chunks or blocks"
    # grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)

def process_chunk(chunk):
    "Return sequence of result lines.  Chunk must be iterable."
    for i, line in enumerate(chunk):
        yield 'file-line {1:03d}; chunk-line {0:02d}\n'.format(i, int(line))
    yield '----------------------------\n'
```

Here is some test code that demonstrates that every line is visited:

```
from StringIO import StringIO

class CtxStringIO(StringIO):
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        return False

infile = CtxStringIO(''.join('{}\n'.format(i) for i in xrange(19*10)))
outfile = CtxStringIO()


# this should be the main loop of your program.
# just replace infile and outfile with real file objects
with infile as ifp, outfile as ofp:
    for chunk in grouper(19, ifp, '\n'):
        ofp.writelines(process_chunk(chunk))

# see what was written to the file
print ofp.getvalue()
```

This test case should print lines like this:

```
file-line 000; chunk-line 00
file-line 001; chunk-line 01
file-line 002; chunk-line 02
file-line 003; chunk-line 03
file-line 004; chunk-line 04
...
file-line 016; chunk-line 16
file-line 017; chunk-line 17
file-line 018; chunk-line 18
----------------------------
file-line 019; chunk-line 00
file-line 020; chunk-line 01
file-line 021; chunk-line 02
...
file-line 186; chunk-line 15
file-line 187; chunk-line 16
file-line 188; chunk-line 17
file-line 189; chunk-line 18
----------------------------
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear in your question, but I guess the calculations you make depend on all the N lines you extract (19 in your example).

So it's better to extract all these lines and then do the work:

```
N = 19
inFile = open('myFile')
i = 0
lines = list()

for line in inFile:
    lines.append(line)
    i += 1
    if i == N:
        # Do calculations and save on output file
        lines = list()
        i = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @halflings ! Yes, my calculation depends on all 19 lines. I will try with your's one. Thanks again!

Comment: I just noticed there's probably an error in my solution though (I might not be checking for the file's end correctly), will modify it in a sec.

Answer (score 2):

This solution needs not loading all lines in memory.

```
n=19
fp = open("file")
next_n_lines = []
for line in fp:
    next_n_lines.append(line)
    if len(next_n_lines) == n:
        do caculation
        next_n_lines = []
if len(next_n_lines) > 0:
    do caculation
write results
```

Comment: @BlueIce it can also deal with cases that the number of lines in the file is not multiple of 19